# Добавление объекта в JSON с сохранением cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

При клике на кнопку в JSON должен записываться дополнительный объект, но получается что объект просто перезаписывается при клике сохраняя только последнее значение. JSON сохраняется в cookie но так же только с последним значением.

```
$('.order-item').click(function() {
        var jsonObj = '{"ecommerce": { "add": { "products": []}}}';
        var itemtype = $(this).attr('itemtype');
        var itemsize = $(this).attr('itemsize');
        var priceitem = $(this).attr('priceitem');
        var quantyti = $(this).attr('quantyti');
        var totalprcie = $(this).attr('totalprcie');

        item = {}
        item ["title"] = itemtype;
        item ["itemsize"] = itemsize;
        item ["priceitem"] = priceitem;
        item ["quantyti"] = quantyti;
        item ["totalprcie"] = totalprcie;

        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
        obj.ecommerce.add.products.push(item);
        $.cookie('cart',obj);   
    });
```

Как добавить объект в JSON во вложенный products и парсить значение если объекты уже есть?

Comment: Вы определяете json строку в в начале функции, а нужно получать ее из cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо сначала получить текущене значение `$.cookie('cart')`, если оно есть.

```
   $('.order-item').click(function() {
        var jsonObj = $.cookie('cart') || '{"ecommerce": { "add": { "products": []}}}';
        var itemtype = $(this).attr('itemtype');
        var itemsize = $(this).attr('itemsize');
        var priceitem = $(this).attr('priceitem');
        var quantyti = $(this).attr('quantyti');
        var totalprcie = $(this).attr('totalprcie');

        item = {}
        item ["title"] = itemtype;
        item ["itemsize"] = itemsize;
        item ["priceitem"] = priceitem;
        item ["quantyti"] = quantyti;
        item ["totalprcie"] = totalprcie;

        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
        obj.ecommerce.add.products.push(item);
        $.cookie('cart', JSON.stringify(obj));   
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но первый объект добавляется на 2 выдает ошибку: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 (var obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);)

Comment: @Дмитрий обновил ответ - добавил JSON.stringify перед тем как определять куки.

Comment: Ошибка до этого была в том, что $.cookie('cart', obj) было равносильно cart=[object Object] т.к. объект автоматически приводился строке (с помощью .toString).